# how a class building its other instances while being constructor

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I want to create a coordinate class while when I instantiate this class, it automatically build its 6 adjacent coordinate, however, when I was doing it, I always encountered stackoverflow problem and I had no good way to solve it. Here is my wrong code, you can easily see the problem, the contructor itself contains itself. So I wonder how can I fix this problem

```
public class Coordinate {

    private final int x;
    private final int y;
    private final Coordinate[] periperal;

    /**
     * The default constructor for Coordinate class that
     * sets up the coordinate to the given integers.
     * 
     * @param x value of x coordinate
     * @param y value of y coordinate
     */

    public Coordinate(){
        final Coordinate adjacent1 = new Coordinate(x, y + 1);
        final Coordinate adjacent2 = new Coordinate(x, y - 1);
            final Coordinate adjacent3 = new Coordinate(x - 1, y + 1);
        final Coordinate adjacent4 = new Coordinate(x - 1, y);
        final Coordinate adjacent5 = new Coordinate(x + 1, y);
        final Coordinate adjacent6 = new Coordinate(x + 1, y - 1);
        Coordinate[] list = {adjacent1, adjacent1, adjacent1, adjacent1, adjacent1, adjacent1};
        periperal = list;
    }
```

I know why I am wrong but I dont know how to fix it. Could anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to describe what you're trying to achieve - and whether you've got any boundaries. If *every* coordinate has neighbours in an infinite space, then clearly you're not going to be able to create them all...

Answer (score 2):

The first line in the constructor recursively and unconditionally creates another instance. In effect, this is a method calling itself.

You need some condition to stop this recursion from going on forever (or rather, until you run out of stack).

Creating an instance for every coordinate in the whole (unlimited) coordinate system will not work. Are you sure you need to have the neighbour coordinates? They could be calculated on the fly later when/if they are actually needed, I guess.

Comment: I think I need them because I used the coordinate to represent a game board and piece on the board can only go the neighbour coordinates just adjacent to it. So could you teach me how to stop this recursion or give me a hint so I can research on it. Thank you a lot

Comment: By just looking at the X and Y coordinates, you should be able to calculate neighbourhood and distances, without having to make extra instances.

Answer (score 1):

@Thilo explained what is wrong with your code (+1). I want to suggest you a solution.
You actually want to create instance of `Coordinate` that holds 6 other instances of `Coordinate`. You cannot call constructor from the same constructor: it produces infinite recursion.

So here are the solutions:

1. Create private constructor that accepts fake argument (just to distinguish between it and "real" constructor). Call it from "real" constructor. This will prevent infinite recursion.
2. Make constructor package protected. Remove code that calls constructor from constructor. Create factory (or factory method) that creates all instances and sets secondary instances to the primary one.

Comment: Could you tell me how to use a fake constructor in this case?  I tried but always had error

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting adjacent coords in the constructor, move it out into a static method called newInstance() and make the constructor private:

```
public class Coordinate {

    private final int x;
    private final int y;
    private Coordinate[] periperal;

    /**
     * The default constructor for Coordinate class that
     * sets up the coordinate to the given integers.
     * 
     * @param x value of x coordinate
     * @param y value of y coordinate
     */

    public static Coordinate newInstance(int x, int y){
        final Coordinate instance = new Coordinate(x, y);
        final Coordinate adjacent1 = new Coordinate(x, y + 1);
        final Coordinate adjacent2 = new Coordinate(x, y - 1);
        final Coordinate adjacent3 = new Coordinate(x - 1, y + 1);
        final Coordinate adjacent4 = new Coordinate(x - 1, y);
        final Coordinate adjacent5 = new Coordinate(x + 1, y);
        final Coordinate adjacent6 = new Coordinate(x + 1, y - 1);
        Coordinate[] list = {adjacent1, adjacent2, adjacent3, adjacent4, adjacent5, adjacent6};
        instance.setPeriperal(list);
        return instance;
    }

    private Coordinate(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    private void setPeriperal(Coordinate[] periperal) {
        this.periperal = periperal;
    }
}
```

Comment: With caveats that coordinates gained from Coordinate.newInstance(1,1).getPeriperal() (if there was such method) would not heve their neighbours set. (In some use case it can be OK, in some not). And calling Coordinate.newInstance(1,1) twice will create two different instances (which can again be OK or not, but if its ok, overriding equals and hash code to make them equal would be probubly good idea)

Comment: Then the peripherals then should be loaded only when the are actually *needed,* but you are right. +1

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong thing wrong.
As other said, you are covering infinite area, and not only this, you are creating each coordinate infinitely times (x,y)creates (x,y+1) and that creates relative to itself (x,y-1) which is the first one.

To prevent these problems, you need to limit the area (when creating coordinates, you need minX,maxX,minY,maxY and test whether coordinate would lie outside, in which case do not create it).
To prevent recursive creating of same coordinate, you need to store somewhere already created and when you need coordinate, look there and if you not find it, create and remember it. This way each coordinate will get created only once.

Better way is first create coordinates for whole board and store them in array (where (x,y) is transforemed to x*width+y, so you can use 1D array.
And them add connections.

But even that is not necessary. You can just use the actual coordinates and compute neighbours when needed. This way you will trade some more computing for large ammount of not used memory (and java stores small objects inefficiently, which hurts for numerous small long lived objects, and retrieving them can be even more costly than recomputing). But premature optimalization is root of evil anyway. So make it work first and only if it is too slow, make it faster.

Another situation would be, if you need potentionaly infinite (but in every actual case limited by what was actualy used) board. In that case you need some lazy approach and avoid storing what you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution:
don't create your adjacent Coordinate objects in the constructor.
Create them in whatever is creating the first point, then use a setter method to set your adjacent coordinates.